# can you solve Simple fetch Error in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, sanity, groq

it keeps showing me this error

[image: 1]

and I've tried to fix it but it still won't budge..

i dont think there is anything wrong with my groq query

I tried changing my groq query from sanity but it still wont work

Comment: try removing await from line 6

Comment: it didn't work, at this point I'm frustrated

Comment: It now shows this error        ( Error: Error serializing `.pageInfo` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value. )

Comment: can you share the screenshot and also the line where it is showing the error?

Comment: Since res is undefined you can't call .json() on it. What are you returning from the `getPagesInfo` function?